# Remove label from input field

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app like this:

```
library(shiny)


UI <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
)
Server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

If i remove the titles like this:

```
UI <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  numericInput("obs", "", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
)
Server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

I still have white space floating above the input fields. Any thoughts on how i an get rid of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NULL` as label if you want empty field:

```
library(shiny)
UI <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
    numericInput("obs", "", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
    numericInput("obs", NULL, 10, min = 1, max = 100)
)
Server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

[image]